# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to tokenize text, but couldn't. How can I solve this?
Here is my problem:
[image]

[image: 2nd image is my problem]

```
#read_text from file

data = pd.read_csv("input data.txt",encoding = "UTF-8")

print(data)
```

Output: Bangla text

```
t = Tokenizers()
print(t.bn_word_tokenizer(data))
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f9f299ecf33d> in <module>
      1 `t = Tokenizers()`
----> 2 `print(t.bn_word_tokenizer(dataStr))`

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\bnltk\tokenize\bn_word_tokenizers.py in bn_word_tokenizer(self, input_)
     15                 `tokenize_list` = []
     16                 `r = re.compile(r'[\s\।{}]+'.format(re.escape(punctuation)))`
---> 17                 `list_ = r.split(input_)`
     18                 `list_ = [i for i in list_ if i`]
     19                 `return list_`

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You are passing data into the tokenizer which is causing an error due to data being a Dataframe and not a string or bytes-like object. Does your dataframe have several columns?

Comment: @ManasSambare I read a bangla Text file. But error in here when I want tto tokenize

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for column in data:
    a = data.apply(lambda row: t.bn_word_tokenizer(row), axis=1)
    print(a)
```

This will print one column at a time. If you want to convert the entire dataframe rather than just print then replace a with data[column] in the code above.

Comment: Can you explain it in details?  here only one line too be tokenize? But how it is possible whole  the text?

Comment: Another queston to you . HOw can remove stopwords in bangla?

Comment: Problem remain Same. It is my input - তাঁর নামটা শুনলেই চোখের সামনে ভেসে ওঠে ব্রাজিল দলের রক্ষণভাগে ডান প্রান্ত দিয়ে এক অক্লান্ত ফুটবলারের সমানতালে রক্ষণ ও আক্রমণ । খেলেছেন ব্রাজিলের ইতিহাসে সবচেয়ে বেশি ম্যাচ । কপালে একমাত্র খেলোয়াড় হিসেবে টানা তিন বিশ্বকাপের ফাইনাল খেলার গৌরবতিলক । তিনি মার্কোস ইভানগেলিস্তা দি মোরাইস । চিনতেশ

Comment: OUtput after your code -                                                                                                     
  t = Tokenizers()
for column in data:
    a = data.apply(lambda row: t.bn_word_tokenizer(row), axis=1)
    print(a)

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3f33446e816e> in <module>
      1 t = Tokenizers()
      2 for column in data:
----> 3     a = data.apply(lambda row: t.bn_word_tokenizer(row), axis=1)
      4     print(a)

D:\anaconda\li
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object